# J : Iverson's `table` function from _A Personal View of APL_

Tags: j

At the very end of [*A Personal View of APL*](http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/APLPersonalView.htm) (right before the references), Ken Iverson gave the following series of J code snippets:

```
[a=. b=. i. 5
0 1 2 3 4

   a +/ b 
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8

   over=.({.,.@;}.)&":@,
   by=. (,~"_1 ' '&;&,.)~
   a by b over a !/ b
+-+---------+
| |0 1 2 3 4|
+-+---------+
|1|1 1 1 1 1|
|2|0 1 2 3 4|
|3|0 0 1 3 6|
|4|0 0 0 1 4|
|5|0 0 0 0 1|
+-+---------+

   table=. /([`by`]`over`)\
   2 3 5 *table 1 2 3 4 5
+-+-------------+
| |1  2  3  4  5|
+-+-------------+
|2|2  4  6  8 10|
|3|3  6  9 12 15|
|4|5 10 15 20 25|
+-+-------------+
```

All of these work for me in J701, except the last, which gives me:

```
   table=. /([`by`]`over`)\
   2 3 5 *table 1 2 3 4 5
|rank error
|   2 3 5    *table 1 2 3 4 5
```

I notice in the [original PDF from IBM](http://web.archive.org/web/20060820163256/http://www.research.ibm.com/journal/sj/304/ibmsj3004O.pdf) that the quotes look more like:

```
table=. /([`by']`over')\
```

But this is a syntax error.

Was there a transcription error converting the PDF to HTML on the J site, or has the syntax of J changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that this is valid J syntax (I mean, for what it is supposed to do); maybe it was then, but not any more. The adverb `table` can be simply defined as:

```
 table =: 1 :'[ by ] over u/'
```

The closest I can get to Iverson's version is:

```
 table =: /([`by`]`over`)
```

but then you have to evoke (`` `: ``) the result of the adverb:

```
 2 3 5 (*table`:6) 1 2 3 4 5
┌─┬─────────────┐
│ │1  2  3  4  5│
├─┼─────────────┤
│2│2  4  6  8 10│
│3│3  6  9 12 15│
│5│5 10 15 20 25│
└─┴─────────────┘
```

Comment: The new syntax is certainly more readable. :) Why do you say `over u/`? I found an updated version of the example in the dictionary (["bordering a table"](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/samp05.htm)), which wrote it as ` 1 : '[ by ] over x/'`... Isn't `u` bind to `*` here, and `x` to `(2 3 5)` ? Your version makes more sense to me, but the discrepancy has my confused.

Comment: Yes, as you can see [here](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help701/dictionary/d310n.htm) `u` is for the left argument, while `x` is for the left argument of the resulting verb. When there is no `u`, `x` is used for the adverb resolution. I dare say, using `x` in the above situation is not correct.

Comment: Quoting [this](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/jforc/writing_your_own_modifiers.htm) >"In very early versions of J, modifiers could not refer to their x and y operands. In those days, a modifier used the names x and y to mean what we now mean by u and v. Modern versions of J continue to execute the old-fashioned modifiers correctly by applying the following rule: if a modifier does not contain any reference to u, v, m, or n, it is assumed to be an old-style modifier, and references to x and y are treated as if they were u and v."

Answer (score 1):

J has changed. Earlier versions allowed adverbs and conjunctions to be defined in ways that are no longer possible.

A version of `table` that is compatible with recent versions appears in the *J Dictionary* under ["Bordering a Table"](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/samp05.htm)